# Get the page number of a Google Docs file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I use Google Script to create a Google Docs file and want to get the page number of this document as soon as I have finished creating the content of the document. I used the following code at the end of my program:

```
var data = doc.getAs("application/pdf").getDataAsString();
    var pages = data.match(/\/Contents/g).length;
    Logger.log(pages);
```

No matter how many pages the newly created document has, the result I get is always `pages = 1.0`. Actually I used the existing code, so I don't understand it well. I really need help. Thank you.

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your whole script and whether I could correctly understand your actual situation, I proposed a modification point. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your actual situation and that was not the solution to your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following situation,

> No matter how many pages the newly created document has, the result I get is always pages = 1.0.

Although I'm not sure about your whole script and whether I could correctly understand your actual situation, I guessed that `saveAndClose()` might be the direct solution to your issue. So, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
doc.saveAndClose(); // <--- Added
// doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); // or DocumentApp.openById("###")

var data = doc.getAs("application/pdf").getDataAsString();
var pages = data.match(/\/Contents/g).length;
Logger.log(pages);
```

- If your script uses `doc` after your showng script, please use `doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); // or DocumentApp.openById("###")`.

#### Reference:

- [saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose)

Comment: I ran a test, of course it was perfect. Thank you very much @tanaike. Also I have more knowledge about `saveAndClose()`.

Comment: @Lê Phong Nguyễn Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Somehow when I copy this code to another Google account, it gives an error: `Exception: Document is closed, its contents cannot be updated.`. @tanaike, Can you help me explain why?

Comment: @Lê Phong Nguyễn About your new question of `Somehow when I copy this code to another Google account, it gives an error: Exception: Document is closed, its contents cannot be updated.. @tanaike, Can you help me explain why?`, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question? In that time, please include more information. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?